# MySQL Message #1064

Tags: mysql, wordpress, syntax, phpmyadmin, message

I have a database that I created when I installed wordpress on my site. I've been using this site for a while now and there are lots of posts there. But today when I went to take a look in the database, I got this error message when I opened myphpadmin.
What should I do? I cant even exported the database.

Error message:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'PLUGINS' at line 1
```

Comment: what query are you using with PLUGINS ?

Comment: I'm not sure. The only thing i have done is installing wordpress and added plugins and themes inside of wordpress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a bug in MySQL according to [here](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=62408)

I'd suggest updating to the latest version of MySqlServer

Comment: Thanks, but how do i update to the latest version of MySqlServer on my host?
I'm using servage.net, btw.

Comment: Are you the server admin?  If so, (at least if it was say on an EC2 amazon box, you could just do the shell command apt-get upgrade).  IF you're not the server admin, you will need to inform them.

Answer (score 0):

No, i'm not. Looks like the host did something. It suddenly started working. Now I have a backup, thank for all answers :)